# Call class from another Project C#

Tags: c#

I really need your help and to figure this out.

My Project:

`AccessProjectMap
-- MainClass.cs
-- ErrorLog.cs (public)
ThreadProjectMap
-- StartThread.cs`

I'd like to make `StartThread` my default project when the project starts. Now I need the ErrorLog.cs file in my ThreadProjectMap. I made a reference and I can actually say `ErrorLog log = new ErrorLog();` which does also work. When I try to use the ErrorLog in `MainClass.cs` it's working too.

However I cannot use `log` inside the main or DoThreading function.

```
class StartThread {

    static string threadRefresh = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("refreshTime").ToString();

    Access ac = new Access();
    ErrorLog log = new ErrorLog();

    static void Main(String[] args) {
        log.LogMessageToFile("== Start Main() ==");
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoThreading));
        t.Start();
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void DoThreading() {
        int refresh = 1;

        while (true) {

            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            log.LogMessageToFile("== Test - inside Thread ==");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not because of different projects/namespaces, instead you are **trying to access an instance member in a static method**.

Make your `log` field `static` and it should compile fine.

```
static ErrorLog log = new ErrorLog(); //Here, make it static

static void Main(String[] args) {
    log.LogMessageToFile("== Start Main() ==");
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoThreading));
    t.Start();
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Both maps have the same namespace. 

When I make log static I get TypeInitializationException?

Comment: `TypeInitializationException` would generally mean that you have some `static` field in your class `ErrorLog` that is not properly being initialized. Check the code, set up break points and see if you can figure it out. Also look at inner exception if there is any, it might give you a better idea

Comment: thanks a lot for pushing me into the right direction again! :) Problem was that it couldn't handle my app.config file

Answer (score 2):

The instance you create of ErrorLog on this line:

```
ErrorLog log = new ErrorLog();
```

Is an instance variable. The `Main` and `DoThreading` methods are static.

You have two options: Either make the ErrorLog static as well, like so:

```
static ErrorLog log = new ErrorLog();
```

Or, just instantiate it inside your static methods.